Collision manifold between shapes
I am implementing the narrow phase collision detection of a 2d physics engine.
The narrow phase takes a list of shape pairs:
[(s1, s2), (s2, s5), ...]

And for each pair, it generates a collision manifold, in case they are colliding.
A collision manifold contain the following data:
Collision Manifold:
- Shape a
- Shape b
- Vector2 normal
- float depth
- Point2D contact_1
- Point2D contact_2

The possible shape types for the pairs are:

Circle
AABB
Oriented rectangle
Convex polygon

My question is:
What should be the manifold data for each possible pair?
For example:
In the case of Circle vs Circle:

